# Python FTP from UNIX to Windows

Tags: python, windows, unix, ftp

I am running a python script on a UNIX server. My aim is to take the file from UNIX server and put it in Windows machine .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
filename = "filename"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
ftp.login("uid", "psw")
ftp.cwd("/my/location")
print filename
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'w').write)
```

My code currently just takes file from one folder in UNIX (`"/my/location"`) and put its in the folder from where I am running the code.  How can I put the file on the Windows Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `import os` then use `os.chdir(r"\where\the\file\should\go")` first:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
import os
filename = "filename"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
ftp.login("uid", "psw")
ftp.cwd("/my/location")
os.chdir(r"c:\somewhere")
print filename
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'w').write)
```

Where Windows keeps the Desktop files depends on which version of Windows you're running, which you haven't told us -- so I'll just give you generic instructions. I trust you know how to find the right folder for the Windows Desktop in your version of Windows.

Comment: Mate I am executing the python script on Unix box where the files are located. I need to send these files to a Windows(Name:MyABC) box.When I run the code I am getting the following error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\MyComp\\c$\\my\\LOcation'`, because the location is on windows and OS command in this case checks for Unix

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for. But the answer was helpful as it helped me learn more. Hence accepting as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and thought that you were running the script on the Windows side, because otherwise `ftp.cwd("/my/location")` is completely wrong -- as you've now discovered. Basically, use `ftp.cwd()` to change the working directory on the remote end, and use `os.chdir()` to change the working directory on the local end. So you'd do `ftp.cwd(r"C:\Windows\Desktop")` (or wherever your Windows Desktop is actually located -- substitute the appropriate path for your *specific* version.)